# Remove-item varibale for path from csv

Tags: powershell, variables, path, import-csv

i have to delete folders based on a excel list, so i have tried to import the execl with import csv but it dosent work. 
The import doesnt fill the variable in the correct format.
This is the code i tried to use:

```
$folders = import-csv G:\Book1.csv foreach ($folder in $folders) {Remove-Item -Path $folder -Recurse -Force}
```

The error is this:
Remove-Item : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '@{Foldername=G' does not exist.
At line:4 char:5
+     Remove-Item -Path $folder -Recurse -Force
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (@{Foldername=G:String) [Remove-Item], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

Remove-Item : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '@{Foldername=G' does not exist.
At line:4 char:5
+     Remove-Item -Path $folder -Recurse -Force
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (@{Foldername=G:String) [Remove-Item], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

Remove-Item : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '@{Foldername=G' does not exist.
At line:4 char:5
+     Remove-Item -Path $folder -Recurse -Force
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (@{Foldername=G:String) [Remove-Item], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

In the CSV in the 1.Line heading stands foldername in line 2-4 are the name of the folders (a, b, c).
This is the CSV:

Foldername
G:\Test\a
G:\Test\b
G:\Test\c

The directory is G:\Test\a , b, c

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61303191/edit) your question and show the first 3 or 4 lines of the `G:\Book1.csv` as [Formatted text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks/22189#22189). From your description it does not look like a CSV file at all..

Comment: I got the XLS File and save it as CSV, can i do anything other? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I have found a Solution, the CSV file was a Problem and the import so i had to modify the CSV File:
"Foldername"
"G:\Test\a"
"G:\Test\b"
"G:\Test\c"

the powershell code is this now:

```
$folders = import-csv .csv | ForEach-Object {

    write-host $($_.Foldername)
    Remove-Item -Path $($_.Foldername) -Recurse -Force     
 }
```